# How to get post id from FacebookShare PostSharingResult

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am sharing video on facebook using GraphSharer and looking for post id in the share completion.

But I am not able to fetch it.

```
sharer.completion = { result in
                        // Handle share results
                        print("Share results : \(result)")

                    }
```

I am getting this on my logs :

```
Share results : success(FacebookShare.PostSharingResult(dictionary: ["video_id": "1455433997844989", "completionGesture": "post"]))
```

So i tried these but didn't work :

1. `let dict = result as! [String:Any]`
2. `result[""]`

   but getting error **ContentSharerResult has no subscript member**

Any idea how to get the value video_id from this result ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `po result.success`on console and see what type it's holding.

Comment: Also, `post_id` should only be returned if your app has been granted `publish_actions` permission. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/

Comment: @Bangdel its already there in logs. I have every permission to do that. I just want to parse that result i am getting.

Comment: @InderKumar error: use of unresolved identifier 'result'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more workarounds I finally got the solution for my problem.
For anyone in future wants to fetch post id.

```
sharer.completion = { result in
            // Handle share results
            print("Share results : \(result)")
            switch result{
            case .success(let shareResult):
                print(shareResult["video_id"])  // Your post id
                break
            case .cancelled:
                break
            case .failed(let Error):
                print(Error)
                break
            }
```